# Problema con preparedStatement

Tags: java, sql

Estoy tratando de ejecutar los siguientes comandos:

```
stmt=con.prepareStatement("CREATE DATABASE ?");
stmt.setString(1, nombreBase);
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Al hacerlo sobre `select` o `insert` funciona pero al hacerlo con estos comandos no me permite hacerlo me arroja un error de sintaxis. ¿Por qué se da esto?

Answer (score 0):

no puedes enviar un nombre de la base de datos usando los binds, debes generar de una su sentencia y enviarlo al `prepareStatement`, algo asi

`String query = "CREATE DATABASE "+nombreBase;`

`stmt=con.prepareStatement(query); 
 stmt.executeUpdate();`

**Nota:** Recuerda que las sentencias preparadas deben ser una instrucción de lenguaje de manipulación de datos de SQL , como INSERT, UPDATE o DELETE; O una instrucción SQL que no devuelve nada.[PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

Comment: Pero y como evito sqlInjection si no lo mando asi

Comment: @LeoT pues lo que estas haciendo es una creacion de base de datos, mas no consultas, ni actualizaciones o eliminaciones;

Comment: Claro pero en si para ejecutar eso ya estoy conectado en una base en especifico en la BD postgres que es la que viene por defecto en postgresql y si no la protejo podrían manipular todas las bases que creo desde ahí, al principio lo estaba haciendo como me indicas pero me puse a revisar la parte de seguridad e hice los cambios correspondientes sin embargo en esta parte no se como evitar ataques  si no es con preparedStatement

Comment: si pero en tu pregunta estas **creando** una nueva **base de datos**, para crear una nueva base de datos no los acepta en los bindings.

Comment: Como me sugieres que lo haga entonces aparte de lo que respondiste al principio

Comment: Nota: `executeUpdate` es para comandos de DML como `insert`, `update`, `delete`. Para ejecutar DDL usa `Statement#execute` o `PreparedStatement#execute`.

Comment: @LeoT no tienes otra alternativa más que sanitizar el parámetro enviado. Puedes usar una lista blanca y negra para la validación o usar un framework que pueda apoyarte con esto.

Comment: La cosa es que normalmente la creación de una base de datos no debería ser algo que sea el resultado de una entrada usuario. Los usuarios solo deberían poder manipular los datos de forma controlada, no la creación ni la estructura de los objetos de la base de datos mismo. El hecho que tu diseño permita esto, esa es la vulnerabilidad. Es mas, significa que tu aplicación se conecta a la base de datos con privilegios elevados, otro problema de seguridad.  Lo que estás haciendo solo deberia permitirse con usuarios de mucha confianza, donde la preocupación de SQL injection no aplica en realidad.

Comment: voy a intentarlo con una lista blanca y negra y pues lo estoy haciendo de esta manera porque estoy trabajando en una aplicación de tipo SaaS en la que al registrarse una empresa tenga su propia BD y maneje de manera separa su información a la de otras empresas                                       Gracias por la idea

Answer (score 0):

Es un poco workaround, pero podrías intentar crear un PL:

```
PROCEDURE crearBD(p_nombre_tabla VARCHAR2(20)) IS
BEGIN
    //llamada dinámica a CREATE DATABASE p_nombre_tabla
END;
/
```

Y desde Java:

```
CallableStatement cstmt = con.prepareCall("{call crearBD(?)}")) {
    cstmt.setString(1,"nombreBD");
    cstmt.execute();
}
```

Comment: Si la preocupación principal por la que OP quería hacer el bind en el PreparedStatement era evitar el SQL injection, esto en realidad no cambia nada. Solo da la ilusión que el código está más protegido, pero al final, de todos modos la llamada es dinámica dentro del SP.

Comment: Tenía entendido que el CallableStatement ya hace un filtrado para evitar SQL injection, ¿no es así?

Comment: En cierta forma, pero este filtrado solo es útil si no tienes SQL dinámico dentro del SP.  En este caso, sería perfectamente válido que le pasara al parámetro el valor siguiente: `"nombreBD; drop database otraBD;"`. ¿Qué pasaría entonces si dentro del SP ese valor se concatena a una sentencia `CREATE DATABASE ` y se ejecuta de forma dinámica? Es solo un ejemplo que tal vez no aplique directamente a Postgres, pero creo que puedes ver la idea y el problema potencial.

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de que JDBC no controla estos casos validando los parámetros?